# D3JS tree example in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jsfiddle

I'm trying to implement [one of the examples](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) found on the d3.js site in JSFiddle and not having any luck.  [Here's what I have so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/JDRay/5j10b7Lq/1/)  I'm not really a JS developer (nor have I ever played one on TV), but I'm usually able to get something going with a little persistence and research (often in that order).  I'm stumped.  What am I doing wrong?

Other than implementing the data block as a variable instead of loading it from a file, I haven't altered the code at all.  In the HTML, I took out one line that referred to the dndTree.js, and moved the CSS to the CSS section of JSFiddle.

At line `804`, the `treeData` variable is first referenced:

```
// Call visit function to establish maxLabelLength
visit(treeData, function (d) {
    totalNodes++;
    maxLabelLength = Math.max(d.name.length, maxLabelLength);

}, function (d) {
    return d.children && d.children.length > 0 ? d.children : null;
});
```

Comment: For starters, where are you trying to pull `flare.json` from?

Comment: `flare.json` is the name of the data file.  As I said, instead of pulling the data in from that file and loading it into `treeData`, I just implement `treeData` directly with the contents of `flare.json`.

Comment: Something similar is done here: http://jsfiddle.net/augburto/YMa2y/

Comment: I found this JSFiddle that implements something very similar to what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/MetalMonkey/JnNwu/  I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.